# $ N_{1} $ , $ N_{2} $ are minimal normal subgroups of $ G $, $ G/N_{1}\cap N_{2} \cong G $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism

Let $ G $ is a finite group and $ N_{1} $ ,  $ N_{2} $ are minimal normal subgroups of $ G $ that $ N_{1} \neq N_{2} $. Suppose $ G/N_{1} $ and $ G/N_{2}  $ are supersolvable. Then $ G $ is supersolvable ? $ G/N_{1}\cap N_{2} \cong G $ ?

Comment: Hint: show that $N_1\cap N_2$ is normal.

Comment: @Arthur Please help me

Comment: This is the standard way of showing that a subgroup is normal: take an $n\in N_1\cap N_2$ and a $g\in G$. If we can show that $gng^{-1}\in N_1\cap N_2$, no matter which $n$ or $g$ we choose, then we have shown that $N_1\cap N_2$ is normal. Once that is done, minimality and non-equality of $N_1,N_2$ will therefore imply that $N_1\cap N_2=\{e\}$, the trivial group, which is what we want.

Comment: @Arthur $ G/N_{1} \times G/N_{2} \cong G/N_{1} \cap N_{2} $ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the homomorphism $\varphi$ from $G$ into $G/N_1\times G/N_2$, given by $\varphi\colon g\mapsto (N_1g,N_2g)$. Then $\ker\varphi=N_1\cap N_2=\langle 1\rangle$ (Arthur's proof above), so $G\cong G/(N_1\cap N_2)\cong {\rm Image}(\varphi)$. As subgroup of a direct product of supersolvable groups, ${\rm Image}(\varphi)$ is supersolvable, and thus $G$ is.